# How to jump into Python debugger in dev server?

Tags: python, flask, pdb

I need to debug a block of code and I'm reaching for `pdb` module.
Debugger isn't giving me the interactive shell I'm expecting though:

```
import pdb

...
...

if not del_data:
    return response_obj, 400
pdb.set_trace()
index = del_data.get('index')
...
...
```

dev server's daemon:

```
gifts_1      | > /usr/src/app/project/api/gifts.py(64)delete()
gifts_1      | -> index = del_data.get('index')
gifts_1      | (Pdb) 172.19.0.1 - - [26/Jul/2020 21:30:17] "DELETE /gifts HTTP/1.1" 500 -
print(index)
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: What kind of server is it? Gevent based?

Comment: It's Flask so I believe it's WSGI (Weirkzurg)